# SSIS job step not being remembered when adding my own command line in

Tags: ssis, command, line, jobs, step

I have the following script (auto generated) to demo this problem. When i add a new job and a job step with my own command line text, the job step isnt remembered at all. I am at a loss at what I am doing wrong, or is this a solid bug with Sqlserver.

What are my work around. I have entered this through SSMS gui and via these scripts. If you uncomment the default command line text and add my own with the word BUG it is not remembered.

I have tried these few ways and read what I can find, but no success. thanks

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'Poo')
   EXEC sp_delete_job @job_name = N'Poo'

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Poo', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'XXX', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [main]    Script Date: 7/01/2019 2:43:21 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'main', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 

        /* problem here */

        @command=N'/FILE "\"\\xxxx\0_Startup.dtsx\""  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 



        --@command=N'BUG', /* uncomment and comment above to demo */
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'X', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20190107, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=180000, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'5a413d73-5bda-4567-a90e-e7341f06a6d1'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out the config is being stored correctly, it is SSMS that is bug ridden and cant display it.

verify with

```
select * from dbo.sysjobsteps
```